# Eloquent relations from multiple joined tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Let's say we have a table `users` and we are left joining multiple tables to it.

```php
        $users = User::query()
            ->select('users.id', 'bananas.id as banana_id', 'dogs.id as dog_id')
            ->leftJoin('bananas', 'banana.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->unionAll($usersWithDogs) // a similar query with a left join on `dogs`
            ->orderByDesc('users.created_at')
            ->paginate(...);
```

We end up with a collection of `User` models with attributes `id`, `dog_id`, `banana_id`.

Now imagine we want to eager load these, but the eloquent relations are based on the one to many relationships, `$user->dogs`, `$user->bananas`.

Trying to find a solution that will do all the following:

a) not break pagination
b) allow ordering on the user table
c) allow eager loading
d) use clean code
e) end up with a collection of users

Brainstorming so far has led to the following options:

1. A union of `bananas` and `dogs`, eager load the `user` relation, then invert the collection (messy code)
2. Dynamic relationships created on `User`, possibly with a macro on `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`. Maybe by leveraging `Model::resolveRelationUsing()`
3. Manual eager loading with a union select with a left join to each table in each arm of the union, then a `whereIn()` to get the related records
4. Restructure the relations so that there is a polymorphic many to many relationship between users and other entities
   e.g.

```
    user_id | model_type        | model_id
    1       | App\Models\Banana | 2
    1       | App\Models\Dog    | 5
```

Maybe I'm missing something obvious...?

Comment: Doesnt `User::with(['dogs','bananas'])>orderByDesc('users.created_at')->paginate()` gives you what you want?

Comment: nope, I need it to be paginated by the elements in the child relations (dogs, bananas). e.g. 10 dogs and/or bananas per page. When there is a left join, there are 1 or many user records for each user.

Comment: So basically there could be repeated users depending on whether they have many dogs/bananas or dogs and bananas, right? Anyways, I dunno how a union would work if column names do not match unless u declare an empty column on both queries, if its latter a left join on both tables should work as well. That aside, once you select `dog_id` and `banana_id`, you can treat user as if it belongs to Dog/Banana; in which case I THINK you can define a belongsTo on User model with FK as dog_id instead of dynamic relationship. This way you can query `with` or `load` the relationship.